# PHP form with script do not do POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, events

i'm new with web programming and i have this problem, I have this little form:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">

<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Orden de Servicio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabla.css">
  <img src="img/logogps.png" alt="GPS" style="float:left; width:64px;height:64px; margin-left:1%;margin-top:1%;">
  <script src="scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function EnableAnom()
      {
          if($('#chkanom').is(':checked'))
          {
            document.getElementById("InputAudio").hidden = false;
            document.getElementById("InputText").hidden = false;
            document.getElementById("InputImage").hidden = false;
            document.getElementById("lblaudio").hidden = false;
            document.getElementById("txtdet").hidden = false;
            document.getElementById("lblimg").hidden = false;
          }
          else
          {
            document.getElementById("InputAudio").hidden = true;
            document.getElementById("InputText").hidden = true;
            document.getElementById("InputImage").hidden = true;
            document.getElementById("lblaudio").hidden = true;
            document.getElementById("txtdet").hidden = true;
            document.getElementById("lblimg").hidden = true;
          }
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="checkprereg.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2 class="text-center">Check PreInstalación</h2><br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_orden" value=<?php echo $idorden; ?> />
    <input type="hidden" name="chkenc" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkenc" value="1">
    <label for="chkenc">Encendido</label><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="chkapg" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkapg" value="1">
    <label for="chkapg">Apagado</label><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="chkcontig" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkcontig" value="1">
    <label for="chkcontig">Continua / Ignición</label><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="chkluces" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkluces" value="1">
    <label for="chkluces">Luces</label><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="chkotra" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkotra" value="1">
    <label for="chkotra">Otra</label><br><br>    
    <label for="videvi">Video de evidencia (arranque):</label>    
    <input type="file" name="videvi" id="InputFile" accept="video/*"><br><br>    
  <label for="chkanom">Habilitar registro de anomalías</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkanom" id="chkanom" value="1" onclick="EnableAnom()" ><br><br>    
    <label for="audanom" hidden="true" id="lblaudio">Audio con detalles:</label>    
    <input type="file" name="audanom" id="InputAudio" accept="audio/*" hidden="true"><br><br> 
    <label for="textanom" hidden="true" id="txtdet">Detalles:</label>
    <textarea name="textanom" id="InputText" rows="5" cols="50" hidden="true"></textarea><br><br>     
    <label for="imganom" hidden="true" id="lblimg">Imagen con detalles:</label>    
    <input type="file" name="imganom" id="InputImage" accept="image/*" hidden="true"><br><br> 
 <button class="button orange" type="submit" value="Submit">Enviar</button>
<button class="button orange" type="reset" value="Reset">Limpiar</button>
</form>
  <p>
            <a href="menu.php">
            <img src="img/home.png" alt="Home" style="float:right; width:64px;height:64px; margin-left:1%;margin-top:1%;">
        </a>
        </p>
</body>
```

I did added a litlle script (EnableAnom()) that hides some inputs with a checkbox, but, with this script the form don't do POST, (I receive all vars empty) if I remove the script, the form works ok.

What is wrong in the script? (I did move up script up, down, without success)

Best regards.

Comment: one thing to note: The `img` tag in the `HEAD` section is incorrect - it should be within the `BODY` somewhere.

Comment: The problem does not appear to be reproducible with the code you have shown. When I copy&paste that into a jsfiddle, the form submits in both cases, with no apparent problems. All the parameters are there, when I check the resulting POST request in the browser dev tools network panel.

Comment: I did correct img tag, thanks, the porblem persist.

Only if I remove script post works.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="hidden" name="id_orden" value=<?php echo $idorden; ?> />`
change to

`<input type="hidden" name="id_orden" value="<?php echo $idorden; ?>" />`

and test first

Comment: While you are at it: Actually it should be `value="<?php echo htmlentities($idorden); ?>"`, otherwise the issue that you want to fix can still happen

Comment: I did change, the porblem persist.